# Javascript: list.indexOf(elm+"") returns index, but list.indexOf(elm) returns -1

Tags: indexof

I was writing a function to remove given elements from an array and then i came to this particular situation:

```
function removeStudent(elm, list){
var elmToDelete = list.indexOf(elm);
console.log(elm + " element");
```

the console shows -1, so the given element couldn't be found in the list. However, if a search it as a concatenated stirng, it will return the index of given element:

```
function removeStudent(elm, list){
var elmToDelete = list.indexOf(elm+"");
console.log(elm + " element");
```

For the record, I'm currently using Chrome version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) in Mac OS.

Comment: how are you calling removeStudent? +"" simply converts elm to a string.

Comment: Here's how I call removeStudent:
`var student;
student = prompt("Which student do you want to remove?");
removeStudent(student,roster);`

Comment: and then? what are you typing then? a name? 1? all?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I simply write a name in the prompt (ie: john) that is already inside the array passed as an argument in removeStudent.